# Centos 6.3 doesn't detect USB drives

Tags: linux, terminal

Unable to locate its file.

In the terminal `fdisk -l` didn't give the expected result. I tried mounting the device using '`mount /dev/sdb1 /media/usb`' but it says mount requires the 'type of device'.

Please suggest ways to get around this problem.

Here is the output of `tail -f /var/log/*log` after plugging in the USB drive.

```
/var/log/Xorg.0.log <==  
[  4224.638] AUDIT: Sun Mar  3 14:35:34 2013: 1784: client 30 connected from local host ( uid=500 gid=500 pid=23902 )  
  Auth name: MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 ID: 180  
[  4224.813] AUDIT: Sun Mar  3 14:35:34 2013: 1784: client 21 disconnected    
[  4852.120] AUDIT: Sun Mar  3 14:46:01 2013: 1784: client 29 disconnected  
[  5168.650] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "SEC", prod id 21825  
[  5168.650] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:  
[  5168.650] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   72.33  1366 1414 1446 1526  768 770 775 790 -hsync -vsync (47.4 kHz)  
[  5178.661] AUDIT: Sun Mar  3 14:51:28 2013: 1784: client 21 connected from local host ( uid=500 gid=500 pid=25073 )  
  Auth name: MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 ID: 180  
[  5178.674] AUDIT: Sun Mar  3 14:51:28 2013: 1784: client 21 disconnected  
[  5179.044] AUDIT: Sun Mar  3 14:51:28 2013: 1784: client 21 connected from local host ( uid=500 gid=500 pid=25074 )  
  Auth name: MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 ID: 180  
[  5559.459] AUDIT: Sun Mar  3 14:57:48 2013: 1784: client 29 connected from local host ( uid=500 gid=500 pid=2011 )  
  Auth name: MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 ID: 180
[  5559.460] AUDIT: Sun Mar  3 14:57:48 2013: 1784: client 29 disconnected
[  5779.037] AUDIT: Sun Mar  3 15:01:28 2013: 1784: client 21 disconnected
[  5779.048] AUDIT: Sun Mar  3 15:01:28 2013: 1784: client 21 connected from local host ( uid=500 gid=500 pid=25111 )
  Auth name: MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 ID: 180  
[  6379.037] AUDIT: Sun Mar  3 15:11:28 2013: 1784: client 21 disconnected  
[  6379.047] AUDIT: Sun Mar  3 15:11:28 2013: 1784: client 21 connected from local host ( uid=500 gid=500 pid=25132 )  
  Auth name: MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 ID: 180  
[  6628.138] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "SEC", prod id 21825  
[  6628.138] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:  
[  6628.138] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   72.33  1366 1414 1446 1526  768 770 775 790 -hsync -vsync (47.4 kHz)  
[  6628.152] AUDIT: Sun Mar  3 15:15:37 2013: 1784: client 28 connected from local host ( uid=500 gid=500 pid=25148 )  
  Auth name: MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 ID: 180  
[  6636.586] AUDIT: Sun Mar  3 15:15:45 2013: 1784: client 28 disconnected  
[  6637.183] AUDIT: Sun Mar  3 15:15:46 2013: 1784: client 21 disconnected  
[  7355.394] AUDIT: Sun Mar  3 15:27:44 2013: 1784: client 21 connected from local host ( uid=500 gid=500 pid=2011 )  
  Auth name: MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 ID: 180  
[  7355.394] AUDIT: Sun Mar  3 15:27:44 2013: 1784: client 21 disconnected
```

Comment: What was the output of "fdisk -l /dev/sdb" ?   Stabbing in the dark, have you tried 'mount /dev/sdb /media/usb' - ie simply mounting the entire disk as a block device - this is technically possible in some cases.

Comment: @davidgo The command fdisk -l /dev/sdb just returned the prompt after a pause.Yes i have tried mount /dev/sdb /media/usb but in vain.

Comment: Are you certain the device hard disk is being recognised as "/dev/sdb" ? (If you are unsure, you can try "tail -f /var/log/*log" from a terminal, plug in your drive and see what it says - Please post this information as it could be useful)

Comment: @davidgo I am a newbie to terminal environment.There wasn't any mention of /dev/sdb when i ran the above command and it did not return the prompt.I guessed it as /dev/sdb from the output of 'dmesg | grep SCSI' in which there was a line 'sd 6:0:0:0 [sdb] Attached SCSI removable device'.

Comment: The log file you attached does not show a USB drive.  This might mean that the problem is the USB drive is not being detected by the system at all, but it might also mean it was simply scrolled off the screen or something. What distro do you use ?  [ Note that when you plug and unplug a disk, the "sd" device could change, which might mean its not sdb - the first key to solving your problem is finding the correct device ID]

Comment: @davidgo The distro I use is Centos 6.3.How do I find the device ID?

Comment: What does the command "for each in `ls /dev/sd?`; do udevadm info --query=all --name=$each | head -8; done" return ?

Comment: first line in the output says device node not found

Comment: Without seeing the output, that implies the OS is not detecting the hard disk.